# Unable to download data from Google Cloud Storage to local directory using Google Cloud SDK Shell

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

Up until a year ago I was able to download folders and directories from my bucket on Google Cloud Storage, now I keep getting errors when I try to download using the same commands that previously worked. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the command I'm imputing:

> gsutil -m cp –r “gs://cloudberrybackup12febbf3-0864-42a2-bd04-2f8cbc97a94d/CBB_Cutler Server” “C:\GCS”

and I keep getting the following error:

> [winerror 123] The filename directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect: C:\GCS\CBB_Cutler Server\E:'

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, you've probably got an object in that bucket with a name that starts with `CBB_Cutler Server/E:`. And when gsutil tries to create that directory structure on your Windows machine, it can't due to the reserved character, the colon, being present.